# Angular 2 , Webpack 2 , AoT compilation

Tags: angular, webpack

Below image depicts my Angular 2 project directory structure.

[image]

Sub folders "Author" , "Book" and "Category" have files related to feature modules.

I am using webpack 2 for module bundling , Tree shaking and AoT compilation.

Below is the content of webpack.config.js file

```
'use strict';
 const webpack = require('webpack');
 const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/main.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new AotPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: './src/tsconfig.json',
        entryModule: './src/app/app.module'
    }), 
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        compress: false
    })
    ],
    output: {
       filename:'./src/bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Now when run "webpack" , it displays below error

> ERROR in ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\author'

and this error is displayed only when "AotPlugin" is included in webpack.config.js file

My OS is windows 10 , any idea what could be the reason for this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest trying Angular Cli to get your bearing with how webpack 2 and AOT works.

Since your app looks simple enough I think using it will greatly simplify everything webpack / angular build related.

https://cli.angular.io/

In the latest beta of angular-cli an `ng eject` method has been implemented that converts the angular cli app to expose webpack's config file and the inner workings. Maybe you will find your answer there.